# Php mysql search advice

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a php mysql search script which is searching in a very big database (over 2 000 000 rows) and i want it to be fast. I want it to have a spell checking and a smart word detection for example to query phone when user input is phrone or hpone. So the best way i found is with `REGEXP` . But when i use regexp with mysql with a complicated expression it is kind of slow. Do you have any advice for me?
Regexp example for phrone to match phone

```
[a-zA-Z]*[phrone]{3,}[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

Comment: I do not think, regexp is your way to go for that problem. Have a look at fuzzy search. (Just a general advice. I don't know how to implement this with mysql)

Comment: Could you please show us an example of your database table?

Comment: is it possible to choose first letter first? i mean: if user press "a", you first chooses varchars begins with "a" and then do the regex

Comment: Regex on a large database will always be slow. You'll need something specifically designed for this sort of searching, like https://www.elastic.co/.

Comment: @Webber Depor no.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this doc:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

this enables you to perform search for things you have described. 
if you want more power and features, please use elasticsearch or other search engine (SOLR), they are blazingly fast and have more features.

Comment: Good idea but i want it to make pretty smart so i do not think this is great. I thought to use a dictionary . A txt file with all the words and select the closest match

Comment: For example if user input is phonde how do i select phone with FULLTEXT?

Comment: @user8708554 The likelihood of you hacking together a solution that outperforms existing ones like SOLR or Elastic is extremely low.